# How does one decide how many times to test program before good declaring to go?

Tags: manual-testing

Currently I have a program that I'm tentatively done with and I'm comparing the output with the output of a process that is known to be correct.

This is a once a day process.

How many times should I call it good if the output of my program matches the process output?

A week? (5 correct outputs 1 per day)

OR

A month? (20 correct outputs 1 per day)

I don't want any errors on this program as that would be pretty bad as this is an important process.

Comment: The answer could range from 3 times to 10,000 times depending on: need, use, variables, ernironment, knowns, unknown, data, everything.  So this is not an answerable question on this site.

Answer (score 0):

Phase 1
Run smoke tests, if bugs = 0;  Run Tests of the most critical requirements
Else fix bug AND  Run smoke tests

Phase 2
Run Tests of the most critical requirements if bugs = 0; Run Full Regression
Else fix bug AND  Run most critical requirements

Phase 3
Run full regression if bugs = 0; Ready for homologation tests by the business area and THEN Release

if that dont is what you need, you should do performance tests with a load above average so you can see on a long shot how your software will behave on a stress